# Local cloud Gaming (e.g local OnLive)

Tags: lan, cloud, gaming

Is there a software that allows to create OnLive-like server for game for playing in LAN?

Computing power and bandwidth is enough to do such thing, software is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any Cloud Gaming Service you could install at home. If I should guess you want to have a server or normal PC which functions as a "Cloud Game Server", while you are playing with a mobile device?

If this is the case I advise trying to play through a RDP connection. I did not try it myself, but there are several reports in various forums, implying that gaming through RDP is possible (although there could be problems with latency and graphics).